# Blinking cursor in IE in textareas and inputs appears when blur() called

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove blinking cursor from inputs and textareas like this:

```
$('input, textarea').bind('click focus', function (e) {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('disabled')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $this.blur();
        return false;
    }
});
```

But if I click on a field in IE then blinking cursor appears for a moment and only then removed. Please, tell me how can I fix it without using 'disabled' attribute for elements? I use my own css class disabled (not attribute).
Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried binding to the `"mousedown"` event? And why you wouldn't just use the mentioned `"disabled"` ATTRIBUTE?

You can style it whatever you like in css using `:disabled` pseudo-class

Comment: I don't remember why we desided not to use disabled attribute. Maybe it have different behaviour in different browsers.